# Wordpress mysql query no accepting variable

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have been trying to code a mysql query in wordpress but it does not seem to work.
code:

```
foreach ($postList as $curpostid) {
        echo "postID ".$curpostid." + ";
        $sql2 = 'SELECT * FROM wp_mr_rating_item_entry WHERE post_id='.$curpostid;
        $results2 = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_results($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

$postList prints as:

```
Array
(
[0] => 3148
[1] => 3097
[2] => 3048
[3] => 1036
)
```

These post ids do exist, and the echo shows them up fine. If I enter a specific value for $curpostid as one of the array entries the query works. It seems the query is not accepting the variable form the array.
I have tried making the variable as int (int)$curpostid since the field type is bigint but still not working.
Any help appreciated.

I have managed to place the output in a multidimensional array, but now  I am not able to place the values in a single array: 
this is the array:

```
 Array
(
   [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [rating_item_entry_id] => 1
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [rating_item_entry_id] => 2
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [rating_item_entry_id] => 3
            )

        [3] => stdClass Object
            (
                [rating_item_entry_id] => 4
            )

        [4] => stdClass Object
            (
                [rating_item_entry_id] => 5
            )

        [5] => stdClass Object
            (
                [rating_item_entry_id] => 6
            )

        [6] => stdClass Object
            (
                [rating_item_entry_id] => 7
            )

        [7] => stdClass Object
            (
                [rating_item_entry_id] => 8
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [rating_item_entry_id] => 10
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [rating_item_entry_id] => 11
            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [rating_item_entry_id] => 14
            )

    )

)
```

How can I place all the final rating_item_entry_id  values in a single array?
Have tried with following code but I am bit confused and its not working.

```
foreach($results2Array as $result2) {
        foreach($result2 as $res2) {
            echo   $res2['rating_item_entry_id'];
            $ratingentries[] = $res2['rating_item_entry_id'];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add into your script string echo "sql2 ".$sql2." \n";  after generating sql and add its output to your question?

Comment: is it working? `echo "postID ".$curpostid." + ";`

Comment: The echo is working. and the requeted echo by alexnder outputs: sql2 SELECT * FROM wp_mr_rating_item_entry WHERE post_id=3148 sql2 SELECT * FROM wp_mr_rating_item_entry WHERE post_id=3097 sql2 SELECT * FROM wp_mr_rating_item_entry WHERE post_id=3048 sql2 SELECT * FROM wp_mr_rating_item_entry WHERE post_id=1036

Comment: ok, bro, try to run this query in phpmyadmin: `SELECT * FROM wp_mr_rating_item_entry WHERE post_id=3148`

Comment: where is your template file ? is it in theme folder ? or its a custom template  file ?

Comment: to devpro: If i run the query with a specific value as post_id it works. It does not work if the value comes form the array.
This function is in the functions.php file and the $postList array is populated dynamically from another table.

Comment: Problem was ahead of all this, sorry for my silly mistake, some of the data I was trying to achieve had no entry in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach ($postList as $curpostid) {

        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM wp_mr_rating_item_entry WHERE post_id='".$curpostid."'"; //change here
        $results2 = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_results($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: It's your careless mistake I guess.

Comment: Still not working, with your query i get single quotes around the variable value but nothing changes.

Comment: The problem is I was getting an object array inside another array. Placing a value in SELECT instead of * fixed the problem

Comment: The problem actually persists, and I dont understand why the query works with fixed variable and not from array value